# Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) and asynchronous APIs

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, event-handling, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using Twitter API to post tweets. At times this can take some time, so i want to perform the "Tweet posting" operation in the background. For that i'm using GCD, like this:

```
- (void)myClassMethodToPostTweet {
    dispatch_async(network_queue, ^{
        // … construct the tweet message
        NSString *tweet = @"…";

        // … check if network is available
        [self isConnectedToWeb];

        // … initialize twitter API
        TwitterAPIClass *twitterAPI = [[[TwitterAPIClass alloc] init…] autorelease];
        twitterAPI.delegate = self;
        twitterAPI.APIKey = ...;
        twitterAPI.APISecret = ...;

        // … use twitter API to post the tweet
        [twitterAPI postTweet:tweet];
    });
}

...
/* and when the API reports a successful operation, update the required variables and UI */
...

- (void)twitterAPIDelegateMethodReportingOperationSuccess {
    // … update any variables/records

    // … update UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // … UI updation code
    });
}
```

The problem is, I'm not getting the delegate callback! What am i missing?

Comment: Which Twitter API are you using?

Comment: http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try running the Twitter connection on the main thread? If it works on the main thread and not on some background queue, you might have run into run loop issues with `NSURLConnection`. (Just a wild guess.)

Comment: +1 it's a run loop issue.  MGTwitterEngine uses NSURLConnection's asynchronous API for communication, which requires a runloop.  I doubt you'd get this to work with GCD without some major changes to the code.  GCD doesn't play well with run-loop based communication.

Comment: So, what other options do i have? Would NSOperation do the job? (though, i doubt it, because it uses GCD under the hood)

Comment: The Twitter library does not offer you an asynchronous interface? It seems like a natural choice, given that it apparently already uses asynchronous `NSURLConnection`. The code sample you gave us in the question looks asynchronous enough. Does it block somewhere?

Comment: Well, not really! It's the call to [self isConnectedToWeb]; that actually blocks the main thread, but i guess i can work around that. Actually i tried wrapping the Twitter API call into dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... }); to workaround the run loop issue as well, but i was getting crash issue. Weirdly, I'm getting this issue with ONLY one of my Twitter accounts. *still don't have a clue why!*